# Record audio Flutter its work in android and not working in iOS real device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter

```
code I do it
```

[image]

```
permissions
```

[image]

```
Xcode
```

[image]

```
Error
```

[image]
I tried different solution, but nothing working. it is work in android.
I do chatting app with recorder.

Comment: please, don't post code as screenshots... I bet you won't get any answer, most of people will leave this question without links clicking/digging and without possibility for copy/paste (e.g. for searching or fixing bad line and pasting proper code in answer)